# How to get the ZFTool of an older version?

Tags: zend-framework2

I need the [ZFTool](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zendtool.introduction.html) in an older version (`2.1.4`). How / where can I get this?

Answer (score 1):

You can check [their github](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2)'s tags !

For example, for you, it's https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/tree/release-2.1.4

Or you can have a direct download link like here :
https://packages.zendframework.com/releases/ZendFramework-2.1.4/ZendFramework-2.1.4.zip

*Takes lastest download link (https://packages.zendframework.com/releases/ZendFramework-2.2.4/ZendFramework-2.2.4.zip) and change number of version.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I meaned the [ZFTool](https://github.com/zendframework/ZFTool), not the Zend Framework.